# What to do if a Poster finds issue elsewhere in code?

Tags: discussion, answers, self-answer

I did some poking around meta looking for an answer to this fairly specific question, but my search didn't turn anything up. Essentially, I would like to know how SO handles questions that are resolved when the Poster finds an issue elsewhere in their code.

For example [this Poster](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46385496/required-false-for-booleanfield-generates-typeerror) asks a seemingly valid question, then realizes the error is in another section of the code not posted to the SO question, and submits an answer explaining this.

I would argue this is the proper course of action, as he or she realized the mistake and made sure people didn't keep posting suggestions. My question is now that the issue is resolved for the Poster, should the post be deleted? Is it up to the Poster to do so, or is it a job for a moderator?

On the other hand: is this worth something in it's own merit? I understand that maybe others with the exact same problem would find this question and it might prompt them to consider looking at their database implementations, but it's not really a specific answer, nor does it contribute much to the conversation.

For these types of questions/answers (which I concede might be fairly rare), is there any action ordinary users of SO can do to help clean up for the moderators?

If the rarity of this scenario makes it a non-issue, sorry for wasting time!

Comment: Depends on what the issue actually was and if someone else can have the same issue.

Comment: Yeah, I can see how this is in some ways a very specific question! Thanks!

Comment: I'd say leave the question/answer as is. As you said in the question, there is a slight change someone might be helped by the answer. What's the point of deleting/closing something if it isn't actively harmful?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I see two ways to handle that situation:

If you can edit the question to included the problematic part (for example, because the use has posted it in the question) do that. In this case, the question will now include all relevant information and can stay together with the answer.

If this is not possible: I would vote to close as off-topic - "a problem that can no longer be reproduced" because the problem in the question cannot be reproduced by the code.

In the specific case you asked about, I would choose the second option. The answer as is ("There was a problem with the database") will not be helpful to any other user anyway.